# Is an indignant or surprised question a rhetoric question?

Tags: latin, sentences, interrogatives, rhetoric

Learn to Read Latin says on p115

> an (conj.) *introduces an indignant or surprised question expecting a negative answer.* can it really be that ...

Does it introduce a rhetoric question?

Is an indignant or surprised question a rhetoric question? Vice versa?

Does a rhetoric question expect no answer from the audience?